# How to change MaterialFilePicker screen orientation?

Tags: android-layout

I'm setting my android application to landscape orientation for all activities and I'm using the MaterialFilePicker library. However, I can't find the way to set the screen orientation when I enter the MaterialFilePicker window, it is always set to portrait by default. Is there any way that I can change that?